# How To Make join for This Select Query

Tags: mysql

How to  make join query for my select query which is shown below.

```
"select a,b from table1 where d in
 (select d from table2 where column1 ='value1' and column2 > '2' );"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.d = t2.d
WHERE t2.column1 = 'value1' AND t2.column2 = 'value2'
```